# Count Method Java printing correctly

Tags: java, count, format, names

So I have a program that opens a file "input.txt" which contains a list of names. I have multiple methods in order to organize the names, capitalize accordingly, and display them. What I am having trouble on is in the output aspect of the program. When I use the countOccurrence method which I will have shown below, it correctly counts how many times each name appears in the list whether it is a first or last name. The problem is it not displaying the count the way I want it to. I will have the output I get and the output I want shown below and if anyone can help that would greatly appreciated.

```
    public class Names {

public static void display(ArrayList<String> names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i = i + 1) {
        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
}

public static int find(String s, ArrayList<String> a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i = i + 1) {
        String str = a.get(i);
        if (str.equals(s)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}

public static void capitalize(ArrayList<String> names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i = i + 1) {
        String name = names.get(i);
        if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            String firstLetter = "" + name.charAt(0);
            names.set(i, firstLetter.toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase());

        }
    }
}

public static void sort(ArrayList<String> names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size() - 1; i = i + 1) {
        int Min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < names.size(); j = j + 1) {
            if (names.get(j).compareTo(names.get(Min)) < 0) {
                Min = j;
            }
        }
        String tmp = names.get(i);
        names.set(i, names.get(Min));
        names.set(Min, tmp);

    }

}

public static void getNames(ArrayList<String> fn, ArrayList<String> ln) throws IOException {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the input flie?");
    String names = kb.next();
    File inpFile = new File(names);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String firstName = in.next();
        String lastName = in.next();
        fn.add(firstName);
        ln.add(lastName);

    }

}

 private static int countOccurence(String name,ArrayList<String> names){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i =0; i < names.size(); i++){
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(names.get(i))){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
    getNames(first, last);
    capitalize(first);
    capitalize(last);

    ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
        allNames.add(last.get(i) + ", " + first.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("*******All Names******");

    sort(allNames);
    display(allNames);

    System.out.println("\n*****First Name Count***");

    sort(first);

    for(int i =0; i < first.size(); i++){
            int count = countOccurence(first.get(i), first);
            System.out.println(first.get(i) + "        " + count + " times.");
        }


    System.out.println("\n****Last Name Count****");

    sort(last);

    for(int i =0; i < last.size(); i++){
            int count = countOccurence(last.get(i), last);
            System.out.println(last.get(i) + "        " + count + " times.");
        }


    System.out.println("\n****All Names Count****");

    sort(allNames);

    for(int i =0; i < last.size(); i++){
            int count = countOccurence(allNames.get(i), allNames);
            System.out.println(allNames.get(i) + "        " + count);
        }



    *****First Name Count***
    Adriana        4 times.
    Adriana        4 times.
    Adriana        4 times.
    Adriana        4 times.
    Colette        4 times.
    Colette        4 times.
    Colette        4 times.
    Colette        4 times.
    Emmanuel       1 times.
    Gerri          1 times.
    Gretta         1 times.
    Kirsten        2 times.
    Kirsten        2 times.
    Marcia         2 times.
    Marcia         2 times.
    Neva           1 times.
    Shawanda        1 times.
    Tijuana        1 times.

    ****Last Name Count****
    Beres        2 times.
    Beres        2 times.
    Beumer       1 times.
    Hutt         2 times.
    Hutt         2 times.
    Jones        2 times.
    Jones        2 times.
    Koenig       1 times.
    Means        1 times.
    Montilla     4 times.
    Montilla     4 times.
    Montilla     4 times.
    Montilla     4 times.
    Mossman      1 times.
    Sapienza     2 times.
    Sapienza     2 times.
    Shover       1 times.
    Stanfill     1 times.

    ****All Names Count****
    Beres, Kirsten        2
    Beres, Kirsten        2
    Beumer, Gretta        1
    Hutt, Colette         1
    Hutt, Shawanda        1
    Jones, Colette        1
    Jones, Marcia         1
    Koenig, Gerri         1
   Means, Tijuana         1
   Montilla, Adriana      4
   Montilla, Adriana      4
   Montilla, Adriana      4
   Montilla, Adriana      4
   Mossman, Emmanuel      1
  Sapienza, Colette       2
  Sapienza, Colette       2
  Shover, Neva            1
  Stanfill, Marcia        1
```

******* First Names count*********

Adriana 4

Colette 4

Emmanuel 1

Gerri 1

Gretta 1

Kirsten 2

Marcia 2

Neva 1

Shawanda 1

Tijuana 1

******* Last Names count *********

Beres 2

Beumer 1

Hutt 2

Jones 2

Koenig 1

Means 1

Montilla 4

Mossman 1

Sapienza 2

Shover 1

Stanfill 1

******* All Names count*********

Beres, Kirsten 2

Beumer, Gretta 1

Hutt, Colette 1

Hutt, Shawanda 1

Jones, Colette 1

Jones, Marcia 1

Koenig, Gerri 1

Means, Tijuana 1

Montilla, Adriana 4

Mossman, Emmanuel 1

Sapienza, Colette 2

Shover, Neva 1

Stanfill, Marcia 1

Comment: "The problem is it not displaying the count the way I want it to." And how do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: @Turing85 I explained in the question. The first output which is in the code is what I got. What I want to get is the output that follows after the code

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Clone the first and last array lists and use the copies to iterate through. After each processed name remove all instances of this name
2. Create a seperate temp array list and store the already processed names in there, just print the names which are not already stored.

The second way is much more useful, so here goes an example for that:

```
ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i =0; i < first.size(); i++){
    if(!tmp.contains(first.get(i))) {
        int count = countOccurence(first.get(i), first);
        System.out.println(first.get(i) + "        " + count + " times.");
        tmp.add(first.get(i));
    }
}
```

If you're using the tmp variable multiple times, don't forget to clear() it.

Comment: Okay so that worked. But it doesn't display them in alphabetical order. How could I incorperate my sort method in order to display the result in alphabetical order?

Comment: You can sort your list beforehand with: `Collections.sort(yourlist,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`